# how to expand a variable with backslash in bash script

Tags: bash, variable, variable-substitution

i read a line from another file that contains a backslash, and i want to echo this line without expanding the backslash :

*script.sh :*

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < script_sample.txt
```

*script_sample.txt :*

```
echo \"
```

*execution :*

```
PROMPT> bash script.sh
echo "
PROMPT>
```

*instead i would like :*

```
PROMPT> bash script.sh
echo \"
PROMPT>
```

and i can't touch the lines inside `script_sample.txt`, otherwise i would use single quotes `'` or another backslash `\`

i really don't know how to do that ? i supposed it could be something like `echo $'line'` or `${'line'}` that would expand the variable `$line` but not its content, but i can't figure it out

maybe there is something to do with variable substitution ?

Comment: The syntax to read a line of text is [`IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123), not `read line` and the syntax to output a line is [`printf '%s\n' "$line"`](/q/65803), not `echo "$line"`. But maybe even more importantly see: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: all right thank you :)